# Unable to Run (old) Rails Project on c9.io (server won't load)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to clone and work on a copy of this project on c9.io:
https://github.com/asalant/freehub

After doing rvm use ruby-1.9.3 and doing gem install rails, I run bundle install and get this error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160209-19681-1isskta.rb extconf.rb 
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
Makefile creation failed
**************************************************************************
No source for ruby-1.9.3-p551 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
**************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/debugger-1.6.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/debugger-1.6.6/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I removed "debugger" from the gemfile and bundle runs fine after that, but then when I try to start the rails server, this happens:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rails-2.3.17/lib/rails_generator/generators/applications/app/app_generator.rb:7: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
      create  
      create  app/controllers
      create  app/helpers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts
      create  config/environments
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/locales
      create  db
      create  doc
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  log
      create  public/images
      create  public/javascripts
      create  public/stylesheets
      create  script/performance
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/functional
      create  test/integration
      create  test/performance
      create  test/unit
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  tmp/sessions
      create  tmp/sockets
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/pids
      create  Rakefile
      create  README
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  script/about
      create  script/console
      create  script/dbconsole
      create  script/destroy
      create  script/generate
      create  script/runner
      create  script/server
      create  script/plugin
      create  script/performance/benchmarker
      create  script/performance/profiler
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  public/images/rails.png
      create  public/javascripts/prototype.js
      create  public/javascripts/effects.js
      create  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
      create  public/javascripts/controls.js
      create  public/javascripts/application.js
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  log/server.log
      create  log/production.log
      create  log/development.log
      create  log/test.log
```

Why is it re-creating all these files I already cloned from github? Why isn't the server starting? I remember I got this app working before. Weird that this is happening now.

Comment: "when I try to start the rails server," How? What's the command you used?

Comment: `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT`

Comment: And you ran them from inside the directory containing the rails project? What do $IP and $PORT resolve to? (No need to post them; `echo` them and check they're what you expect)

Comment: Yep. When you clone with https://c9.io/new, it clones to the root workspace. $IP and $PORT is c9 specific to bind to their local server in the workspace. It resolves to 0.0.0.0 and port is 8080.

Comment: So you clone ... and you go into the directory, which contains app/ and config/ already, and you run rails s etc, and this happens? I dunno, man.

Comment: Yep. That's right. I'm confused too. Wanna try it out on c9.io and see if it happens to you too? :P